# rotate image with php - any degree

Tags: php, image-manipulation

How to rotate an image with PHP, any degree, without having the filled space? For instance, if I rotate an image 10 degrees, the image rotates fine but the container around (square) gets filled with black. Is it possible to get rid of this, when for example merging 2 images?

Comment: How are you doing the image rotation?  Imagick, GD or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background color in [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) as the third parameter.

I'm not quite sure what you are asking for otherwise.  If you rotate an image, it **has** to remain a rectangle parallel to the axises.  Therefore the image "container" is resized to fit the now rotated image.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the GD/image alpha functions to make the background colour transparent:

```
$newImg = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
```

As john mentions though there will be a background colour, so you will have to make it transparent. the last parameter '127' represents complete transparency with 0 representing opaque. Check out [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

...and make sure you're saving it as a png!